# Firebase App Check don't verify some TWA users

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, firebase-app-check, pwabuilder

Around a year ago, with PWA builder, I uploaded to Google Play my web app as TWA. A few months ago, I turned on App Check verification. Then I started to get 1-star ratings that look this way:

"At the beginning, everything was fine, but now I receive server errors all the time."

Devices with these feedbacks:
Motorola Moto G (5) Plus,
Samsung Galaxy S8,
Samsung Galaxy A20e

In chrome browser on the same devices, everything works fine. On the most devices everything works fine also.

Is there some way to solve this problem?

**Update 1**

I've excluded manually all devices that received a one-star rating and feedback indicating the app isn't working. Here is the link to the [list of excluded devices](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14tnnzP9PC3eeocMZN1Mw2J7ZIrIx78Tq/view?usp=sharing).

In addition, Google Play recently released the "Device Integrity Checks" setting that automatically excludes incompatible devices.

I still receive 1-star ratings from time to time, but the average rating is now above 4.5.

**Update 2**

I reached out to Firebase support and spoke with a developer. They provided me with a list of [supported browsers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/environments-js-sdk), and none of the Samsung browsers are on it.

Additionally, in some instances, AppCheck can produce false-positive results. To address this at an early stage, we can send test the request to the database.

Comment: Would you please share some details and explain the short codes?

Comment: @Tugrul PWA = Progressive Web App. TWA = Trusted Web App. I don't have too many details because I don't own devices where these errors occur. But I assume that app check verification causes these errors

Comment: Hi @MAZ wondering if you found any solution... seems I am experiencing same thing in Android

Comment: @Canada2000I haven't found a complete solution, but I've discovered a way to mitigate the harm, please read updates